# "no working init found" error

Tags: virtualbox

I am having an error with Ubuntu where when I try to run the simulation using Virtual Box it says no working init found. Here is a pic. [It won't let me send the actual picture because I don't have enough credit or something.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmP0c.png) I've looked through so many videos but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone know the fix?

Comment: Have you tried `boot-repair`? Did you allocate enough RAM?